Get pevious value of dataframe by multiple columns and date
Hello I have a specific Stock movement scenario here, where I have 2 DataFrames. The first with the product enter process (df_enter) and another one with the cancel of a product in stock.
I need to find the respective enter movement for each cancel based on columns MOVEMENT, PRODUCT and DATE_TIME. Sometimes there are multiple rows for same MOVEMENT (see Movement 1 and 4). In this case, I need to find the previous Enter Movement based on Cancel Date_time.
I was able to do that searching inside the df_enter for each df_cancel row, but it's terrible slow.
Any idea? I'm getting crazy
df_enter (The product 2 is just to show that I could have different PRODUCTS and it's part of the key to search)



MOVEMENT
PRODUCT
MOVEMENT_TYPE
DATE_TIME
QUANTITY




1
1
ENTER
2024-05-01 11:00
20


1
1
ENTER
2024-05-01 12:00
10


1
2
ENTER
2024-05-01 13:00
50


3
1
ENTER
2024-05-01 13:00
30


4
1
ENTER
2024-05-01 13:10
10


4
1
ENTER
2024-05-01 13:50
30



df_cancel



MOVEMENT
PRODUCT
MOVEMENT_TYPE
DATE_TIME
QUANTITY




1
1
CANCEL
2024-05-01 11:40
5


1
1
CANCEL
2024-05-01 12:10
10


3
1
CANCEL
2024-05-01 13:40
30


4
1
CANCEL
2024-05-01 13:20
40



expected result:



MOVEMENT
PRODUCT
MOVEMENT_TYPE
DATE_TIME
QUANTITY
QTY_CANCELLED




1
1
ENTER
2024-05-01 11:00
20
5


1
1
ENTER
2024-05-01 12:00
10
10


1
2
ENTER
2024-05-01 13:00
50



3
1
ENTER
2024-05-01 13:00
30
30


4
1
ENTER
2024-05-01 13:10
10
10


4
1
ENTER
2024-05-01 13:50
30
10




Looks like a merge_asof with by, please clarify the logic (and break down your example if not)
